# AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession discovery mode Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None while trying to connect UHF-RFID reader

Tags: ios, rfid

I have tried with the sample available in the link provided for ios.

[link for UHF-RFID reader](http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/en/rfid-readers/sl120.html)

I am encountering the error below, hence I am unable to read the device. The error has occurred once the app is installed and before connecting any UHF-Reader device

> IvrJack.RU01.Demo[505:110937] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: IvrJack.RU01.Demo).